# Properties with different names null when posting to MVC Controller but not WebApi Controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have a model called Purchase with various properties:

```
public class Purchase
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "amount", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int Amount
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "currency_code", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string CurrencyCode
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The JSON is:

```
{
  amount: 3000,
  currency_code: "USD"
}
```

The controller is:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class ProtoController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPurchaseManagerFactorySelector purchaseManagerFactorySelector = null;

    public ProtoController(IPurchaseManagerFactorySelector purchaseManagerFactorySelector)
    {
        this.purchaseManagerFactorySelector = purchaseManagerFactorySelector;
    }

    [Route("opt/proto/index/{identifier}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string identifier)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("opt/proto/index/{identifier}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string identifier, Request.Purchase purchase)
    {
        IPurchaseManager purchaseManager = purchaseManagerFactorySelector.GetFactory(identifier);

        return View();
    }
}
```

When the JSON is posted to an ApiController all the properties are populated correctly, however when the same JSON is posted to a Controller only Amount is populated - CurrencyCode is null.  I briefly added a new property called Currency_Code and that was populated, it seems like the JsonProperty attribute is being ignore under MVC?  I added the DataMember attribute, however that didn't have any effect so I removed it.  Json.Net is being used, however I don't understand what the difference is?

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the Request.Purchase from the arguments and try the [FromBody] attribute for parameter binding.

If all you're changing is the Controller inheritence from Controller to ApiController than I'm not sure but it sounds like your message headers.

If you make the call in Chrome and use the inspect tools you should be able to inspect the headers in each call you make and see what's being populated

Comment: thanks for your response. In the end I used an ApiController to handle the post - still don't understand the difference...